# Limiting size of bbcode [img]

Tags: javascript, html, bbcode

I have a bbcode parser that turns,

```
[img]imageurl[/img]
```

bbcodes into,

```
<img src="imageurl" alt="" />
```

The only problem is, I want to be able to enforce a maximum width and maximum height on these images without messing up the aspect ratio, but I cannot check the size and do resizing math before hand since the bbcode parser is not that smart. Is there a way to enforce an aspect ratio respecting maximum size of an image without any knowledge of the image's dimensions using inline css or javascript?

I know I could change the bbcode parser to set a maxwidth for the tag's style, but this does not seem to work on IE6.

Comment: Leave IE6 behind. It needs to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css:

```
img {
  max-width:30em;
  max-height:10em;
}
```

probably combine with a container, so you only have images inside your bbcoded posts max-sized instead of every image on your site:

```
div.post img { … }
```

Comment: the original post was only changed after i posted my answer. remember that IE6 is now almost a decade old. i thought it must've been dead by now …

Comment: if you set only width or only height, browsers will scale images and keep their aspect ratio. this will then only work for landscape, respectively portrait pictures though

Comment: @knittl yes, but i don't want to stretch pictures that are smaller than the max width or height. I only want them to be sized down if they are greater in size than the max.

Comment: they will not be stretched if you only use one of the two css properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it possible to do it client-side AND support IE 6(Why in heavens would you want to?) AND support modern browsers without a ton of hoop-jumping, nasty Javascript or CSS.

Is there a reason you can't do it server-side? You are going to have to do some sort of validation server-side since javascript and css are easily removed/shut off.

Comment: the images in all likely hood will not be on my server.